# SQL Insert statement with inner query not working

Tags: sql, database, amazon-redshift

Continuation of [AWS Redshift Table Delta Load Plan's Guidance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55646325/aws-redshift-table-delta-load-plans-guidance)

The select given in the below query works fine and returns the new inserts in the stage table:

```
SELECT A, B, C, D, E, F, G
      FROM TABLE_STAGE A
     WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT B.ID
                     FROM TABLE_FINAL B
                    WHERE B.B = A.B
                      AND B.C = A.C
                      AND B.D = A.D
                      AND B.E = A.E);
```

but when I am trying to insert those into the final table using the below statement, it fails:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_FINAL values
(SELECT A, B, C, D, E, F, G
  FROM TABLE_STAGE A
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT B.ID
                 FROM TABLE_FINAL B
                WHERE B.B = A.B
                  AND B.C = A.C
                  AND B.D = A.D
                  AND B.E = A.E));
```

Is the query right, for getting only those rows where the composite key is new and doesn't exist in the final table. What is the most efficient way of doing that, if this is not the right solution. How to do it?

Comment: How is the code failing?

Comment: The second query is simply invalid. If you want to use a SELECT as the source for an INSERT, then remove the `values` clause

Comment: I did and it worked. Thanks! Can you also please look into the previous query (I've given a link of) and tell me if this is the best way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try this one:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_FINAL 
SELECT A, B, C, D, E, F, G
  FROM TABLE_STAGE A
 WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT B.ID
                 FROM TABLE_FINAL B
                WHERE B.B = A.B
                  AND B.C = A.C
                  AND B.D = A.D
                  AND B.E = A.E);
```

Answer (score 2):

When doing an insert, you should always include the list of columns:

```
INSERT INTO TABLE_FINAL (A, B, C, D, E, F, G)
    SELECT A, B, C, D, E, F, G
    FROM TABLE_STAGE A
    WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT B.ID
                      FROM TABLE_FINAL B
                      WHERE B.B = A.B AND
                            B.C = A.C AND
                            B.D = A.D AND
                            B.E = A.E
                     );
```

If this fails, then the most common reason would be inconsistent types in the columns.  It is also possibly that you are not assigning a value to a column declared as `not null` that has no default value.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But is there a better way of doing this reconciliation job?